# How to count number of directory in S3 using spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, listdir

I have a problem to count the number of the folder in a S3 specific directory with Spark Scala.

Directory structure:

```
source/20220309/client_1/file_1.csv
source/20220309/client_2/file_1.csv

source/20220308/client_1/file_1.csv
source/20220308/client_2/file_1.csv
```

so i am looking for count 20220309 and 20220308. So the count will be 2. I do not want count for nested folder just top level folder count.

Comment: I see no reason to use Spark for this. Just use regular aws sdk methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hadoop.fs` lib:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import java.net.URI
    
    
val path = "s3a://bucket/prefix"
val fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), new Configuration())
val dirs = fs.listStatus(new Path(path)).count(_.isDirectory)
```